# Android new LocationSettings and Geofencing

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location, android-geofence

I'm trying to do this since 7 days with no results. The problem is ResultCallback, for geofencing I need ResultCallback while for LocationSettings I need ResultCallback, is there a way to do this?
I appreciate some tips...
I'm using latest Google Play Services 7.0
Thanks for your support :)

```
public class GeofenceIntentService 
       extends IntentService 
       implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, 
                  ResultCallback<Status>, ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {

    // onResult for geofencing
    public void onResult(Status status) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResult");
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "status.isSuccess()");
        } else {
          String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(getApplicationContext(),
                status.getStatusCode());
          Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        }
    }

    // onResult for LocationSettings
    @Override
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
                startLocationUpdates();
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to" +
                        "upgrade location settings ");

                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                    // in onActivityResult().
                    status.startResolutionForResult(BaseActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                }
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog " +
                        "not created.");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Log.i(TAG, "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Log.i(TAG, "User chose not to make required location settings changes.");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code, explain what you've done so far, and explain what is not working?

Comment: Yeah, after reading the question I don't know what you're asking about...

Comment: @AlexBaker: In the afternoon I'll provide a sample...

Comment: @MarianPaździoch: I would like to have LocationSettings + Geofencing in a single activity...

Answer (score 1):

> I had the same problem and this is what I did

**Class Definition:**

```
public class Activity/Service extends AppCompatActivity/IntentService implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, 
        OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ResultCallback<Status> {
   ...
}
```

**For GeofencingApi:**

```
public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        // Log.e(TAG, "Not connected");
        return;
    }

    try {
        PendingResult<Status> result =
                LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        getGeofencingRequest(),
                        getGeofencePendingIntent()
                );

        result.setResultCallback(this); 
    } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
        logSecurityException(securityException);
    }
}
```

**For SettingsApi:**

> Used chaining to setResultCallback

```
protected void checkLocationSettings() {
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationSettingsRequest
            ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                    final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                            Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
                            if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
                                mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
                                setButtonsEnabledState();
                                startLocationUpdates();
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to" +
                                    "upgrade location settings ");
                            try {
                                status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog " +
                                    "not created.");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
}
```